# Server Object Code to CSOM C#

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, csom, .net

I am new to office 365 Developement.
I want to write below code in CSOM in office 365 for a remote event receicer.
But dont know exact methods.

```
SPUser loggedInUser;
SPSite spsite = null;
SPWeb spweb = null;

string strLoggedInUser = properties.UserLoginName;
loggedInUser = properties.Web.EnsureUser(strLoggedInUser);
try
{
    SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
    {

        using (spsite = properties.Site)
        {
            spsite.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
            using (spweb = properties.Web)
            {
                spweb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                SPList taskList = spweb.Lists["Tasks"];
                string filename = addedFile.Name.Substring(0, addedFile.Name.LastIndexOf('.')) + "-" + DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyyyyhhmmss") + addedFile.Name.Substring(addedFile.Name'.'));
                SPFile file = spweb.Files.Add(spweb.Url.ToString() + "/" + Tasks.Title.ToString() + "/" + filename, addedFile.OpenBinaryStream());

                file.Item["Author"] = loggedInUser.ID + ";#" + loggedInUser.LoginName;
                file.Item["Editor"] = loggedInUser.ID + ";#" + loggedInUser.LoginName;
                file.Update();
                Tasks.Update();
                spweb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: please post the complete code. You have posted incomplete code

Comment: I need only for that code only. i just want to know what to write instead of using (spweb = properties.Web)  n spsite = properties.Site in csom

Answer (score 4):

As per your comment I am writing this answer.

If you are working with CSOM then there will be no class prefix as "SP". From your code I can say that this code you have written in Event receiver or Feature receiver. That's why it is getting **`Site`** and **`Web`** objects from `properties`.

For CSOM the code should like

<strike>ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(SiteUrl);
    clientContext.Credential = credentials;
    Site site = clientContext.Site;
    Web web = clientContext.Web;</strike>

**Updates**

---

As per your comment it seems that you are working with RER for SharePoint Online.
From [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1043978/Remote-Event-Receivers-RER-in-SharePoint-Online) you can get basic working code for your requirement.

In this scenario above code will not work and it should be used as shown in the given link.

```
using (ClientContext clientContext = TokenHelper.CreateRemoteEventReceiverClientContext(properties))
  {
    if (clientContext != null)
    {
      clientContext.Load(clientContext.Web);
      //do something
      clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
    }
  }
```

Comment: will this code work with event receiver??

Comment: are trying to create event receiver for SharePoint Online with CSOM code?

Comment: Yes a Remote Event Receiver for O365